# Cython, is there a way to create lists of only one type ? (Unlike Python-lists)

Tags: python, list, cython

In my `Group` class, there must be an attribute `particles` which should be an array-like **but resizable** type that can **only** hold `Particle`-instances.
Both classes, `Group` and `Particle` are declared using `cdef`.

As Python-lists can carry any Python-object, I thought there might be a more performant way of declaring some kind of C-list that does only accept `Particle`-instances.
In C it would be something like `List<Particle> particle = new List<Particle>();` i think.

Is there any equivalent for Cython or should I just stay with the Python-list ?

Comment: C++ lists in C ? ^^ Not arrays, I need a class holding class-instance with variable size, just like the Python list. But I thought if the list would only hold one type of instances there might be a more performant c-type.

Comment: Your question is the programming equivalent of "Should I use a hammer?". The answer is the same.

Comment: You can pretty easily write a Python `list` subclass that accepts instances of only one type, or tries to coerce them to same, but Python being Python, it is also easy to circumvent this if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question begs to be asked : why do you want this ?

- is it for efficiency (looping over the array) or to lower memory footprint ?
- do you need an array or a linked list would be enough ?
- is your particle class a simple struct or something with behavior/method ?

Depending on these, the best solution goes from using a python array to numpy or a stl container.

( Note, for example, that looping over python list in cython could be quite efficient. )

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you'll gain any performance but if you want to make sure that the list only contains certain kinds of data...

```
class Group(Object):
    #...
    def isParticle(self, p):
        return hasattr(p, "anAttributeOnlyParticlesHave")
    def getPartiles(self):
        return filter(self.isParticle, self._Particles)
    def setParticles(self, newParticles):
        self._Particles = filter(self.isParticle, newParticles)
    particles = property(getParticles, setParticles)
```

Again, that's not too fast but it's a direct answer to your question.

You might gain something by writing a C module -- I'm not sure.  If you really need performance, you're using the wrong language.

Usually, with Python, typical speed gimmicks don't work.  There's enough caching and optimization going on under the hood that you typically don't gain a lot by thinking in C-like terms --- unless you're writing C modules.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can simply use the same vector class from cpp:

```
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef class Item:
    cdef int amount
    cdef str description

def allocate():
    cdef vector[Item] bunch_of_items
    for i in xrange(100):
        bunch_of_items.push_back(Item())
```

To compile:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


ext = Extension(
    "extension_name",            
    ["module_name.pyx", ],     
    language="c++",         
    libraries=["stdc++"],
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}
    )

setup(
    name = "name",
    cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules = [ext]
)
```

Just keep in mind that you can't pass this vector list back to python unless you convert it to a python list.

Comment: getting: module_name.pyx:8:16: Python object type 'Item' cannot be used as a template argument

Comment: seems that this error happens with recent versions of Cython - i tried it with 0.15.1 (a version which was released round about the time FabrizioM wrote his solution) and it works

Comment: You can't create a vector of a `cdef class` you can only create a vector of some primitive types or a `cdef struct`.

Comment: Even if this "worked" in the past, it would have been a reference counting disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the linked list as a cython struct.  I have set the type of val to `int` but you can set it to any struct type.

```
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc

cdef struct link:
    int val
    link *next


cdef link * create_link(int v, link *prev_link):
    cdef link *x = <link *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(link))
    x.val = v
    x.next = NULL
    if prev_link is not NULL:
        prev_link.next = x
    return x
```

You can then create a pointer to dynamically allocated link objects.

```
cpdef many_links(int n):
    cdef link * l = NULL
    cdef link * f = NULL # keeps track of the first elem in the list 

    for i in range(n):
        l = create_link(i, l)
        if f == NULL:
            f = l

    # Write out the linked list to a python list
    cdef list r = []
    c = f
    while c.next != NULL:
        r.append(c.val)
        c = c.next
    r.append(c.val)

    return r
```